# Create new object from existing object with new values Angular / Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

I am working on an Ionic 3 project,which uses Angular.

I have a JSON object like below called person.  However, I have a Ionic toggle button which enables
 various sections based on whats returned from person.

```
person  = { name: "peter", job: "programmer", home: "somewhere"};

person_checked_values = {}
```

In order to update my toggles I need to pass a boolean.  The keys are the same.  How can I dynamically build a new object off of
 whats returned from person **KEYs**, but set the value as true so person_checked_values results like below?

```
person_checked_values  = { name: true, job: true, home: true};
```

I tried to foreach loop person and create a new object from that, but keep getting undefined and stumped. FWIW - I am using _lodash as well so if there is possibly someway to use help from that library its available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` to get all of the keys. You can then combine that with the `.reduce` function of arrays to build an object.

```js
let person = {
  name: "peter",
  job: "programmer",
  home: "somewhere"
};

let result = Object.keys(person).reduce((obj, key) => {
  obj[key] = true;
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. Works perfectly.